# How to get media info with PHP?

Tags: php, media, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I have several movies with "mov" and "mkv" extensions on my server and I want to get media info like size, time, audio streams, video streams etc. via PHP.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The [GetID3](http://www.getid3.org/) library has a [matroska sub-library](http://gitorious.org/ampache/ampache/blobs/8b27b6aee2e7662f1363692f647aff2d70720063/modules/getid3/module.audio-video.matroska.php), I think that it should be able to do what you want though I've not tried it myself.